# How to assign Direct value to dynamically created 2 dimensional array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to use Direct initialization of a 2d array, which is dynamically created using given function.

```
int** allocate2D(int m, int n) {
    int **a = (int **)malloc(m * sizeof(int *) + (m * n * sizeof(int)));
    int *mem = (int *)(a + m);
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        a[i] = mem + (i * n);
    return a;
}
```

I have a function that allocates the memory and returns the base address and I have random list of numbers that should be assigned to that dynamically allocated memory. 
For Example, here in this, I have assigned directly,

```
int a_11[2][2] = { a[1][1], a[1][2], a[2][1], a[2][2]};
```

but I want to assign these values like

```
int **a_11 = allocate2D(n, n);
a_11 = { a[1][1], a[1][2], a[2][1], a[2][2]};
```

but it's giving an error. How can I solve this? Is there any explicit way to assign values?

I just started learning C and it would be very kind if your help would be descriptive enough for me to understand and in the simplest form.

 Thank You :)

Comment: OT: This is not a 2D array - aka aray of array

Comment: Short answer is: No, you are trying to use an initializer-like construct to assign to a pointer. That will never work

Comment: ASIDE: Your `allocate2D` is assuming that `_Alignof(int *) >= _Alignof(int)`. While that is quite likely to be the case, it is not guaranteed. Some padding may be required between the last `int *` and the first `int` stored in the allocated memory.

Comment: Note that `int a_11[2][2] = { a[1][1], a[1][2], a[2][1], a[2][2]};` is not an assignment; it is a variable declaration with an initializer. Similarly, `int **a_11 = allocate2D(n, n);` is also a variable declaration with an initializer. Initializers can only be used in declarations. (Well, they are also used in _compound literals_, but that's a different topic that doesn't apply here.)